# How to ssh to DCOS instances on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-mesos

I just followed the [steps to create a DCOS 1.7 env](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/aws/).

Now when I try to ssh a slave instance it's asking me a password to connect on the machine.

Is there a default password, where does this password comes from?

Comment: Use the Key Pair (`KeyName`) provided in the Specify Details page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:
https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/sshcluster/

To SSH to a master node:

```
$ dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader
```

To SSH to an agent node:

```
$ dcos node ssh --master-proxy --mesos-id=<mesos-id>
```